# Can I use Transifex comment to contact SE devs?

Tags: support, localization

Ja.SO moderators have been used below "Add as issue" button or mention feature on Transifex to contact SE devs for localization issues. Some of these were answered, but we haven't gotten a reply nowadays.

[image]

Should I use ask on MSE instead of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site's meta is probably more appropriate, since we do have a process in place for handling those, and it doesn't depend on a single dev responding to a ping. It should get you a quicker response, since it'll make that site's/language's CM aware, and able to triage and prod the developers with it.

Of coure including a link to the problematic string in transifex might help, although note that the Id fields there can change, so I always try to provide a link the via the key, e.g. [`https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/-1?key=d4c2876d17e583cc21a9703bd2fcfdde`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/-1?key=d4c2876d17e583cc21a9703bd2fcfdde)